# Opened my React Native project in Xcode, where is my code?

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I recently had to install a react native module that needed configuring in Xcode, but I've been using Visual Studio (VS) Code for many months now on my project. So I opened the workspace file in the project's 'ios' folder.

I can not find any of my App.js code or src files while in Xcode. How do I continue my project in Xcode? Or do I need to continue using VS Code, and just run the saved files in Xcode/iPhone simulator?

p.s. I am not using Expo

Answer (score 2):

You wont get any code in your xcode project, while running your app on android or ios the App.js or other react-native code is bundled, so to change or view react-native code use another editor like [VS-Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Comment: So do i continue coding my react-native project in VS Code (while keeping XCode open), then save it in VS Code, then click 'Product->Run' in XCode?

Comment: In XCode? How? (sorry i'm new to XCode)

Comment: `command + shift + k` : to kill `command + b` : to build `command + r` : to run

Comment: Again, in XCode?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is for only Apple products, there is no JS(X) syntax support, eslint and etc. so, i highly recommend to continue your RN app development in another IDE/Editor, which supports JS(X) and many other major features that need for RN development.